# Locking per ASP.NET session

Tags: c#, asp.net

OK some background. I have something similar to this:

```
class ConnectionFactory 
{
    public IConnection Connect()
    {
        if (User.IsAuthenticated) {
            return InternalConnect(User.Username, null);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public IConnection Connect(string username, string password)
    {
        return InternalConnect(username, password);
    }
    private IConnection InternalConnect(string username, string password)
    {
         IConnection connection;
         var cacheKey = Session[CacheKeySessionKey] as string;

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cacheKey)) {
            connection = HttpCache[cacheKey] as IConnection;   
         }

         if (!IsGoodConnection(connection) {
            connection = MakeConnection(username, password); // very costly
            cacheKey = Session[CacheKeySessionKey] = // some key
            HttpCache[cacheKey] = connection;
         }

         return connection;
    }
    private bool IsGoodConnection(IConnection conn)
    {
        return conn != null && conn.IsConnected;
    }
}
```

I'm currently running into a concurrency problem where that `Connect()` is being called multiple times and creating multiple `IConnection`s per request. I only need one. It is being injected using an IoC container into various instances. `MakeConnnection` is very costly as it spins up a WCF channel.

*My question is:* How can I lock the `InternalConnect` calls *per session*? I don't think locking *per request* is the right way to go as multiple requests can happen per user. I certainly don't want to lock for every call, as this will give bad performance.

I think that doing this is a bad idea:

```
lock(Session.SessionID)
{
   // Implementation of InternalConnect
}
```

*Note:* The username and password overload is what I call only on login.

Comment: what do you mean by isgoodconnection ?

Comment: @Beatles1692 - its just a method to check that its not null or if it gets disconnected.

Comment: what IoC container are you using? Can you show your IoC configuration?

Comment: why can't you lock the method the usual way . I mean use an object to hold the lock so no other thread can create a connection until the first one has done its job and then if the connection state remains valid no other connection will ever generated?

Comment: @AnthonyShaw - its an abstraction around ninject that binds to the `Connect()` method.

Comment: @Beatles1692 - because I don't want to block all requests for just one.

Comment: Since you're using an DI container, why not use the 'per web request' lifetime? Most containers support this or have an extension for this.

Comment: @Steven - i dont want it to automatically dispose the object automatically - i need to persist the connection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is just untested code, from the top of my head, but it may work?

```
// globally declare a map of session id to mutexes
static ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> mutexMap = new ConcurrentDictionary();

// now you can aquire a lock per session as follows
object mutex = mutexMap.GetOrAdd(session.SessionId, key => new object());
lock(mutex) 
{
    // Do stuff with the connection
}
```

You would need to find a way to clear old sessions out of the `mutexMap` but that shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Could you not just add the lock object to the users session?

Comment: @rdans, That will only work for the in memory session store as other session providers will serialize the object as part of the save process.

Answer (score 1):

This is a utility class I use, I can't remember how much of it wrote but I think it is based on code by Stephen Cleary.

It handles async (due to the Nito NuGet package), is concurrent (can handle multiple callers) and tidies up the lock afterwards (the finally clause). You just need to give it a unique key and the function to execute.

```
using Nito.AsyncEx;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static class ThingLocker
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, AsyncLock> locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AsyncLock>();

    public static async Task ExecuteLockedFunctionAsync(string key, Func<Task> func)
    {
        AsyncLock mutex = null;

        try
        {
            mutex = locks.GetOrAdd(key, new AsyncLock());

            using (await mutex.LockAsync())
            {
                await func();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (mutex != null)
            {
                locks.TryRemove(key, out var removedValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'd use it like this;

```
await ThingLocker.ExecuteLockedFunctionAsync("user id etc.", () => { DoThingHere(); } );
```

You could pass it the address of an async function instead which would make it look tidier.

Comment: This ensures that all requests for a key is serialized, which means (I believe) that each block of code you want to protect would need to have a key that is a combination that identifies both the session AND the block of code - "[SessionId]+[CodeBlockId]" - or else unrelated protected code blocks wouldn't ever be allowed to run in parallel. 

Do I have that right?

Comment: ...and a second question: why is async aspect required?  Isn't a lock a lock, regardless which thread it runs on?

Comment: Sorry, all knowledge of this question has been garbage collected out of my head. I remember there was a reason for the async but can't recall.

Answer (score 0):

I would have ninject create the class as a singleton and then store the connection within the factory class itself.

When you make the call to InternalConnect, check to see if `_connection` is null or not. If it is, new up a new IConnect and assign it to _connection

Comment: thats what i'm doing basically. the `ConnectionFactory` is the only one how to know that the connection is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion :
Have Connection maker object that has the logic of MakeConnection in it and it locks the whole process the usual way.when a session starts store a connection maker in it and call this method in internal connect method .

here's what I mean :

```
public class ConnectionMaker
{
private object _lock=new object();

public IConnection MakeConnection()
{
lock(_lock)
{
//
}
}
}
```

and then in your Session_Start you can have :

```
Session["ConnectionMaker"]=new ConnectionMaker();
```

and then in your internal connect :

```
if(! IsGoodConnection(connection))
{
var connectionMaker=Session["ConnectionMaker"] as ConnectionMaker;
connection=connectionMaker.MakeConnection();
....
}
```

Comment: i'm trying to keep this out of the global.asax since this is all in a library. so `Session_Start` is not applicable.

Comment: well you can add it to session the first time you hit the library.In your login process for example

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to store an object in each users session directly.

The lock would look like this:

```
lock (Session["SessionLock"]) { 
    // DoStuff 
}
```

and you could create the object in the global.asax when each session is started

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["SessionLock"] = new object();
}
```

doing it this way means the lock object is automatically removed once a session ends.